# webdriver 3 beta2 unable to close window

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I wish to update to selenium webdriver 3 beta 2 to test compatibility.
Selenium WebDriver: 3.0.0-beta2 
Firefox: 48.0 
OS: Windows 7 
Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class GeckDriverTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/test/resources/wires.exe");
//      System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "src/test/resources/geckodriver.exe");
//      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/test/resources/geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        cap.setCapability("marionette", true);
        cap.setCapability("firefox_binary", "firefoxbinarypath");
        WebDriver browser=new FirefoxDriver(cap);
        browser.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org/");
        browser.findElement(By.linkText("Download")).click();
        browser.close();
    }
}
```

But browser does not closes. 

 It closes if I use `browser.quit()` But throws error:

> 1472391805470 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 56555
>   1472391808818 Marionette  INFO    startBrowser
>   95d29b68-b0bb-487a-915c-4896cfaa09ee
>   1472391808831 Marionette  INFO    sendAsync
>   95d29b68-b0bb-487a-915c-4896cfaa09ee
>   1472391809520 Marionette  INFO    sendAsync
>   95d29b68-b0bb-487a-915c-4896cfaa09ee
>   1472391809653 Marionette  INFO    sendAsync
>   95d29b68-b0bb-487a-915c-4896cfaa09ee
>   1472391827467 Marionette  INFO    sendAsync
>   95d29b68-b0bb-487a-915c-4896cfaa09ee
>   1472391827483 Marionette  INFO    sendAsync
>   95d29b68-b0bb-487a-915c-4896cfaa09ee [Child 6088] ###!!! ABORT:
>   Aborting on channel error.: file
>   c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp,
>   line 2046 Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error
>   communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. Build info:
>   version: 'unknown', revision: '31c43c8', time: '2016-08-02 21:57:56
>   -0700' System info: host: 'mrunal-laptop', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_45' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>   Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false,
>   marionette=true, appBuildId=20160726073904, version=, platform=XP,
>   proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0,
>   firefox_binary="firefoxbinarypath",
>   acceptSslCerts=false, browserVersion=48.0, platformVersion=6.1,
>   XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=Firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true,
>   platformName=Windows_NT, device=desktop}] Session ID:
>   95d29b68-b0bb-487a-915c-4896cfaa09ee  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:670)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:706)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:531)
>     at practise.GeckDriverTest.main(GeckDriverTest.java:20) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: UnixUtils may not be used on Windows
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.getProcessId(ProcessUtils.java:188)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.getPID(UnixProcess.java:222)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$300(UnixProcess.java:201)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:132)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:155)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:196)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:94)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:649)
>     ... 3 more

[image: Firefox Browser throwing error on using quit]

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new `DesiredCapabilities` instance.

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
```

instead of

```
 cap.setCapability("marionette", true);
 cap.setCapability("firefox_binary", "firefoxbinarypath");
```

Comment: that is already there..and it makes no difference if we name it as cap or capabilities